# Why is Rails-6.1 loading blank page instead of completing link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6.1

Upgrading rails base to v6.1.7 with ruby v3.1.

This code currently works on existing code:
<%= link_to page.navlabel, :action => page.action_name, :controller => page.controller_name %> and creates a correctly formed tab and link (tab: home, link: localhost:3000/file/home).

Using upgraded rails app.,  tab and link are still correct. However, when the tab is clicked, a [image]blank page is displayed (although the window selector for safari shows the link and hitting the refresh button does load the page.)

Here is the log file:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.7 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.6.5 (ruby 3.1.0-p0) ("Birdie's Version")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 64564
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2022-11-30 19:19:55 -0800
   (0.5ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
   (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Started GET "/file/home" for ::1 at 2022-11-30 19:19:55 -0800
Processing by FileController#home as HTML
  Page Load (0.2ms)  select * from pages where parent_id is NULL and accs_level = 0;
  ↳ app/models/page.rb:7:in `find_public'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering file/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered file/home.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 6.9ms | Allocations: 10863)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 13.6ms | Allocations: 22105)
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 14.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms | Allocations: 39198)


Started GET "/file/design" for ::1 at 2022-11-30 19:20:00 -0800
Processing by FileController#design as HTML
  Page Load (0.3ms)  select * from pages where parent_id is NULL and accs_level = 0;
  ↳ app/models/page.rb:7:in `find_public'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering file/design.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered file/design.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.7ms | Allocations: 1473)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 19.5ms | Allocations: 10289)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 20.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 11904)


Started GET "/file/design" for ::1 at 2022-11-30 19:20:05 -0800
Processing by FileController#design as HTML
  Page Load (0.7ms)  select * from pages where parent_id is NULL and accs_level = 0;
  ↳ app/models/page.rb:7:in `find_public'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering file/design.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered file/design.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 3.2ms | Allocations: 1183)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 19.8ms | Allocations: 9918)
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 20.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms | Allocations: 11162)
```

Note that other than about 6ms in the Completed 200 OK line, both loads (first via tab click) second by clicking refresh seem to be the same.

I really do not understand what to do/check next.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem appears to be a javascript call used by google analytics to track the application.  The script was located (before I removed the code) in the '/views/layouts/application.html.erb' file.  I think the javascript needs to be updated for the new filename??  Anyway, when that script is removed, tabbed pages open as expected.

I will have to research google analytics later.